# Icons that do not resize in Folium

Tags: python, style, html, folium

My understanding is that Folium still does not have capability to create labels for polygons. Tooltips do not work for my use-case since I can have hundreds of small polygons and I don't want users to have to scroll manically around to find what they're looking for.

To work around this gap, I am calculating the centroid of each polygon and then placing markers on those locations. Then, I can style the icons using HTML to create labels.

However, this is not ideal since the icons are staying at the same size on the map regardless of zoom level. This relative sizing makes my map look awful the further one zooms out:

[image: img1]

Is it possible to create icons which have a fixed size on the map? I want these markers/labels to stay inside the polygon and not scale as the users change zoom levels.

I have tried using text-size-adjust but this is not doing the trick (tried running the notebook in Firefox and Edge).

```
html='<div style="text-size-adjust: 0">xxx</div>'
```

Relevant code:

```js
#place the markers on centroid locations
m.add_child(folium.Marker(location = coordinates, icon=DivIcon(
    icon_size=(100,100),
    icon_anchor=(40,2),
    html='<div style="font-size: 10px; color:red; font-weight: bold; text-size-adjust: 0; text-align: center">%s%s%s</div>' % (text_1,text_3,text_2)
    )))
```